# React-redux useDispatch() Uncaught TypeError

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a simple component to dispatch an action using the React Redux hook `useDispatch` - and I'm getting an error.  I've trimmed the component down to where the error occurs.  It happens when the useDispatch function is called.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const MyComp = () => {
  useDispatch()
  return null
}

export default MyComp
```

This is the error I'm seeing in dev console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at MyComp (MyComp.js?cc4c:4)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js?d018:12938)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js?d018:15020)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?d018:15625)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?d018:19312)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js?d018:19352)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?d018:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?d018:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?d018:256)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?d018:18578)
```

I've trimmed this down further so there are no parents in the react tree.

```
const store = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyComp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Module Versions

```
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
```

Comment: I had the same issue, i solved it by installing https://github.com/facebookincubator/redux-react-hook

Comment: Could you log `useDispatch` (not `useDispatch()`), see what kind of object it is? Otherwise the only thing that could break would be `configureStore`. Could you include the code for this? Maybe try using a simple `createStore(() => ({}))` instead to pinpoint the issue further

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you have the exact same React and ReactDOM versions installed in your `node_modules`, and that there are no other copies of React or ReactDOM anywhere in there?  Most issues with using hooks comes down to having multiple copies of React being loaded.  Also, does this occur with any of the built-in React hooks, like `useState()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working - I think by just stopping, building, restarting the app.  I didn't expect `useDispatch` to need this, so I can't explain why that would have helped.

A note - I did try `useSelector` and that did work, I could output the useSelector variable to console after import from react-redux (console.log of useDispatch was undefined).  I could tell at that point I was on the right version of React, and this was probably a problem of my system.

So, if you are having a similar issue.  Try a full react app restart.  Confirm you are loading the correct version of react.

Answer (score 22):

In my case, I was doing:

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react'
```

instead of:

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
```

‍♂️

Comment: Oh, my god me too! Thanks for posting :)) I have faith that this error will be very popular!

Comment: 100%!!! This was my problem too. OMG, this mistake is VERY hard to track down because the error is so generic and updating your version is a red herring. UGH! Thank you @zgreen.

Answer (score 2):

upgrading from

```
"react-redux": "6.0.1",
```

to

```
"react-redux": "7.2.0",
```

fixed it for me

run `npm outdated` for an overview, and then `npm update react-redux` to update redux

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `@reduxjs/toolkit`, and assumed `react-redux` was already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and the fix was to update "react-redux". 
Initial package.json was like this:

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
```

The problem disappeared after installing `react-redux@7.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I use "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
I fix this by remove "react-redux": "^7.2.2"